# Displaying user control in parent form panel

Tags: c#, winforms

The first line is able to clear the panel but doesnt seem to show the usercontrol in the panel in the parent form.

```
panel1.Parent.Controls.Clear();

if (panel1.Parent == null)
    return;

messagessent uc = new messagessent();
uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel1.Parent.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you use `panel1.Parent`? In this way, you remove all controls not from the panel itself, but from the parent control on which this panel is located.

This action removes the panel itself. And, accordingly, the panel does not have a parent now. The `Parent` property becomes `null`.

I suppose you need to write like this:

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();

messagessent uc = new messagessent();
uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Comment: To note that this method: `[Control].Controls.Clear()` should never be called if the intention is to replace the old Controls with new ones. `ControlCollection.Clear()` doesn't dispose of the objects it contains. A backwards loop should be used to dispose of the Controls. Or enumerate the collection and dispose at `0` (if it's not a time-sensitive procedure).